# How may I change the color of lines in macro \framebox?

Tags: framed

In \framebox I do not see any color options. I have trying to look at its definition using \show to define a new command but what \show shows does not provide any help

Comment: `\framebox` uses the current colour, so you could do `\textcolor{red}{\framebox{\textcolor{black}{<content>}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have great demands, the command command `\fcolorbox` might be enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{green}{white}{Hello world}

\myfbox{Hello world}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ivan, what I want is to put a blue frame in every page of my document, there is an old solution for this in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68464/vector-frame-on-all-pages now it runs in a single page, it does not work if the document has several pages. With framebox I am able to do this but only with black lines. I was looking for the definition of framebox to define a new command colouring the hrules, I looked for the definition with \show and searched the tree of .sty files to no avail

Comment: Maybe it's best if you open a new question: "how to put a blue frame in every page of my document?", which is actually your question here. The link you provided works even in document with several pages.

Comment: I copy-pasted the solution using tikz and it worked as long as the text does not extends more than one page, only if I manually insert \newpage commands it works for more pages. The solution given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559677/page-borders-on-specific-pages-followup-to-an-answer-from-another-question works but I do not see how I can change the color.

Comment: I found it, using the answer given in 559677 and simply adding \color{blue}:

Comment: \AddToShipoutPicture{
  \thinlines\color{blue}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
  \put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
\framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}

Comment: Again, the code available here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68464/vector-frame-on-all-pages puts a box on each page. Anyway, to change the color in the last solution you provided use: `{\color{red}\framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}` in place of `\framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}`

Comment: Yes, I found it thanks a lot Ivan