# How to put frame around each page with white space buffer so that text are do not touch the frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, typography, textwidth, frame

I like to put frame around each page. Only around the text area of the page. Not including the header and footer.

I am also using `fancyhdr`. After some struggle, I got the following.

But the frame around the text area is too close to the text itself. I am not sure how to add extra space. Should I make `textwidth`  itself smaller? Or make frame wider? And how to do these things.  This is what I have now:

[image]

I am using Tikz code I found on the net and made small modification to change thickness and color of the frame. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancyhdr 

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% default is 0pt
\fancyhead[R]{{\footnotesize\scshape\thepage}}

\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% default is 0pt   
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw[line width=.5pt,rounded corners,gray] (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.north west)
          -- (current page text area.south west) -- (current page text area.south east) -- cycle;
  }
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % 4 for main TOC must be in preamble
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\begin{document}
\title{My most important work\vspace{-8pt}}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle  
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Need something similar to  [Vector frame on all pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68464/vector-frame-on-all-pages)

[image]

But I could not make the above work with fancyhdr , it messed it up. Will keep trying.

The space buffer does not have to be too large. I just do not like the text touching the frame, makes it hard to read.

I basically need something like this:

[image]

using TL 2023 with lualatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `fit` library and just a node?

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node [fit=(current page text area),draw,inner sep=10pt] {};
  }
}
```

You can modify `inner sep` as desired.

[image: framed page with breathing space]

[image: showing header as well as footer outside frame]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancyhdr 

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% default is 0pt
\fancyhead[R]{{\footnotesize\scshape\thepage}}

\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% default is 0pt   
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node [fit=(current page text area),draw,inner sep=10pt] {};
  }
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % 4 for main TOC must be in preamble
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\begin{document}
\title{My most important work\vspace{-8pt}}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle  
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, I believe the `background` package may be deprecated in favour of the new hooks (but this would be another topic!).